# Use where clause in insert on duplicate key update

Tags: mysql, insert-update

As I know I can't use a where clause inside a Insert statement but in here what I want to do is I want to insert a new row if same kind of row not exist else I need to update that row. so I need to use where clause to do that. this is my query but it is not working because of where clause. can someone help me on this.

Thank You.

```
"INSERT INTO "
                . "`leaves_count` "
                . "(`leave_cat_id`, `leave_days_count`, `emp_number`) "
                . "VALUES ('$req_lv_cat', $req_lv_day_count, '$empNmbr') "
                . "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE "
                . "leave_days_count = leave_days_count + ($req_lv_day_count) "
                . "WHERE "
                . "(leave_cat_id = '$req_lv_cat' AND emp_number = '$empNmbr')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use merge statement. It will do "If exist UPDATE else INSERT".

```
MERGE <hint> INTO <table_name>
USING <table_view_or_query>
ON (<condition>)
WHEN MATCHED THEN <update_clause>
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN <insert_clause>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i am posting example i hope it will help to you

```
 INSERT INTO table (id,a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
 VALUES (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY
 UPDATE a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d, e=e, f=f, g=g;
```

Comment: In my case I have to concern about both the leave_cat_id and emp_number. that is why I tried to use where clause. as your example it is not concern about that.

Comment: ok you can go for the conditional statements with php coding i hope it makes you simple